# php how add pause in script?

Tags: php, curl

We are have a code:

```
<?php 
function cURL_AutonavigatorRu($level = false, $model_id = false){
    #http://www.autonavigator.ru
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.autonavigator.ru/dispatcher.pl');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36"); 
    $headers = array
    (
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate',
        'Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'
    ); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.autonavigator.ru/my/offer_add/");

    if($level == '1'){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'class=list&method=make&show_all=1&vehicle=car&type=used');
    }
    elseif($level == '2' && $model_id){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'class=list&method=model&show_all=1&vehicle=car&type=used&make_id='.$model_id);
    }
    elseif($level == '3' && $model_id){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'class=list&method=modif&show_all=1&model_id='.$model_id);
    }
    else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'class=list&method=modif&show_all=1&model_id='.$model_id);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode(iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",$result), true);
    return $json['list'];
}


$ArrAuto = cURL_AutonavigatorRu('1');

foreach($ArrAuto as $auto) {

    echo $auto['value'].'<br>';


    //sleep(2);
    $AllModif1 = cURL_AutonavigatorRu('2',$auto["id"]);
    var_dump($AllModif1);
    echo '<br><br>----------------------------------<br><br>';

}
```

We are have problem - web site block curl and not give results for each `$AllModif1 = cURL_AutonavigatorRu('2',$auto["id"]);` in one time(in curl we get null).

Tell me please how make to pause the script that cycle `foreach($ArrAuto as $auto)` worked every 5 seconds?

P.S.: How make pause 4 secound between cycle?

P.P.S.: we are know about sleep() but i not get result with it see please [prntscr.com/4ylm9y](http://prntscr.com/4ylm9y)

Comment: About all those "just use `sleep()`" answers: You need to make sure, that you program doesn't trigger [a timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Comment: @Boldewyn i know about `sleep()` but i not get result with it see please http://prntscr.com/4ylm9y

Comment: Do you exceed the time given by the max_execution_time setting?

Answer (score 2):

Use [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php):

```
foreach($ArrAuto as $auto){
  //Your amazing code here

  sleep(4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Add `sleep(4);` in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

just add `sleep(5);` in your `foreach()`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
sleep(4);
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php